# Decode QRCode Windows Phone 8 using QR code library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, qr-code

I use "Qr Code library" in NuGet packages to work with QR Codes and simply decode the QRCode in WinForm application like this :

```
    var bm = new Bitmap(@"C:\Capture.bmp");
    var qr = new QRCodeDecoder();
    string text = qr.Decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(bm));
    MessageBox.Show(text);
```

the QRCodeBitmapImage class get a Bitmap object and convert it to QRCodeImage to decode it , my problem is in Windows Phone we have BitmapImage instead of Bitmap class!

the library is very simple but don't have useful documentation ..., they just say support Windows Phone in description of NuGet library .

any idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: If you're talking about http://www.nuget.org/packages/MessagingToolkit.QRCode/, it mentions "Windows Mobile", not phone.

Comment: @PeterRitchie yes i use it , the library have a QRCodeImage interface , i'm trying to implement it for my class ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a good article from `Nokia Developer Community`. This article shows `how to use the Optical Reader Library`. It explains both how to integrate the Optical Reader Task into a Windows Phone 8 app in order to `read QR and other barcodes`, and how to extend the library to support other processors for image enhancement and decoding.

you ca try this: [Optical Reader Library for Windows Phone 8](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Optical_Reader_Library_for_Windows_Phone_8)